# In OAuth2.0 should client credentials be sent as post params or as the transport header?

Tags: oauth-2.0

In OAuth2.0 the option is there to send the client credentials (consumer key and secret) as post parameters or as in the http transport header. Most of the identity vendors now support both.

But what should be the best practice to be used? Even if vendors support both, from client program perspective, what should be the best way to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Good question! The answer, it depends on the app and the OAuth grant type being used :P

Form a *client* perspective if you're talking about a web app (maybe with the implicit flow), then using cookies is probably better because they're less exposed to exploiting techniques.

This article may clarify details for you https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage#jwt-cookie-storage.

Comment: in client_credentials grant, what should be the best?

Comment: I'd say transport header, if using cookies they're not accessible through JS and offer an additional layer of security since you can, for example, set rules and flags on your server to only accept HTTPS or requests from a specific client.